# Increasing efficiency of Pandas / Python search

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Got a fairly simple few lines of code that are absolutely crushing my computational power. Hoping the hive mind can help improve my efficiency.

I'm running an analysis project for our HR guys, and they're looking to correlate employee trips with work types performed on those trips.

I have two dataframes:

df1 (work trip list, approximately 37,000 rows):

EmployeeID, Start_Date, End_Date

df2 (work types performed, approximately 135,000 rows):

EmployeeID, Work_Date, Work_type

(all dates are Pandas Datetime objects)

This is the code I'm currently using (python with Pandas):

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    ID = df1.iloc[i,0]
    Start_Date = df1.iloc[i,3]
    End_Date = df1.iloc[i,4]
    df_this_trip = df2.loc[(df2['EmployeeID']==ID)]
    df_this_trip = df_this_trip.loc[(df_this_trip['Work_Date']>=Start_Date)&(df_this_trip['Work_Date']<=End_Date)]

for j in Work_Types:

    df1[j].iloc[i]= len(df_this_trip.loc[(df_this_trip['Work_type']==j)])
```

My intention was for df_this_trip to include a list of the work performed by a given employee on a given trip, then the second for loop counts the types of work he/she does.

The two lines of code beginning with df_this_trip are just crushing me time wise. A sample run of 1000 work trips (of those two lines alone) took five minutes to run. The j loop only added a few seconds. Extrapolating out, all 37,000 trips will take about 3 hours.

Any tips?

Comment: You should use a join, not loops.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too memory-intensive, but you can just perform a merge on EmployeeID and then filter out according to dates. After that, a simple groupby and count.

```
df1.merge(df2, on="EmployeeID").query(
    "Work_Date >= Start_Date and Work_Date <= End_Date"
).groupby(["EmployeeID", "Start_Date", "End_Date"])[["Work_Type"]].count()
```